# Python Regex replace all newline characters directly followed by a char with char

Tags: python, regex, replace, newline

Example String:

```
str = "test sdf sfwe \n \na dssdf
```

I want to replace the:

```
\na
```

with

```
a
```

Where 'a' could be any character.

I tried:

```
str = "test \n \na"
res = re.sub('[\n.]','a',str)
```

But how can I store the character behind the `\n` and use it as replacement?

Comment: use str.replace('\n','')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a capture group:

```
>>> s = "test sdf sfwe \n \na dssdf"
>>> >>> print re.sub(r'\n(.)', r'\1', s)
test sdf sfwe  a dssdf
```

- Search regex `r'\n(.)'` will match `\n` followed by any character and capture following character in group #1
- Replacement `r'\1'` is back-reference to capture group #1 which is placed back in original string.
- Better to avoid `str` as variable name since it is a reserve keyword (function) in python.

If by **any character** you meant any non-space character then use this regex with use of `\S` (non-whitespace character) instead of `.`:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'\n(\S)', r'\1', s)
test sdf sfwe
 a dssdf
```

Also this lookahead based approach will also work that doesn't need any capture group:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'\n(?=\S)', '', s)
test sdf sfwe
 a dssdf
```

Note that `[\n.]` will match **any one of** `\n` or literal dot only not `\n` followed by any character,

Answer (score 1):

Find all the matches:

```
matches = re.findall( r'\n\w', str )
```

Replace all of them:

```
for m in matches :
    str = str.replace( m, m[1] )
```

That's all, folks! =)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way for you so you don't have more spaces in your text is the following:

```
string = "test sdf sfwe \n \na dssdf"

import re
' '.join(re.findall('\w+',string))

'test sdf sfwe a dssdf'
```